# What's the meaning of Configuration (Local/Centralized) on create a agent in openAm

Tags: openam, opensso

It shows:

> Where agent properties are stored. Local is the server on which the agent is running. Centralized is the OpenAM Server

And pdf shows:

> Location of Agent Configuration Repository
>   Indicates agent's configuration located either on agent's host or centrally
>   on OpenAM server.
>   If you change this to a local configuration, you can no longer manage the
>   policy agent configuration through OpenAM console.

I still don't know the meaning.

If I set to **Centralized** which it can be controlled in openAm right?

For example, I have 2 server  A for openAm and B is the APP Server , now I install a agent in B server and in B tomcat it have their own setting, so is that means only the configuration in openAm will affect the tomcat of server B ?  I don't think so... It will sync to  OpenSSOAgentConfiguration.properties ? Hot-Swap ? I changed some  value on openAm but not changed in OpenSSOAgentConfiguration.properties....

I was confused~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have understood it,  OpenSSOAgentConfiguration is not being updated with central configuration. When using central configuration OpenSSOAgentConfiguration is not used at all. 
Whne you set configuration to central, all configuration is done in OpenAM.

i think most properties are hot swap, this i indicated below the propertie on the configuration page. Sometimes I have experienced that I have to restart the agent to get it to load new configuration

Answer (score 0):

In additions to Stefan's response.

configuration will only change immediately if the agent is running in notification mode. Otherwise you have to wait until the agent refreshes its config.

However notification mode can not be used for

Apache 2.0 agents

and you need 3.3.0 Web Agents to get notifications working for Apache 2.2 and 2.4 agents